# Spring Data SimpleJpaProvider

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data

I am trying to use SimpleJpaProvider and below is the code snippet.. I am unable to make an update as in hibernate's SaveandUpate .. unable to determine where my logic is missing?

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepo extends TestBaseRepo<Company,java.lang.Integer>{
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TestBaseRepo <T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>    {}

public class TestBaseRepoImpl <T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T,   ID> implements TestBaseRepo<T, ID> {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestBaseRepoImpl.class);
        @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
        private EntityManager entityManager;

       public TestBaseRepoImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {

           super(domainClass, em);
       }
```

I updated xml config to my factorybean

Now in my service class, I am autowiring 'CompanyRepo' as repot and calling
repot.save(sr.getCompany());
Company entity already exists in DB but this should be an update.. ( as in hibernate's saveandupdate).. This throws duplicate record error. Does save method supposed to check for existing entity and make an update ??

Comment: Why are you trying to extent SimpleJpaProvider?

Comment: CrudJpaRepository's save() method does not check for existing entity and SimpleJpaRepository save() checks and updates if exists. So I want to use SimpleJpaRepository class but want to create a common repository which all entity repositories can use..

Comment: You've created and and documented quite a mess here. What is `SimpleJpaProvider`? What is the `CrudJpaRepository` you're talking about? None of these types exist. You obviously haven't followed the reference documentation (http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) on that topic as your code looks heavily different from what is suggested there. Please make sure you follow the instructions and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @OliverGierke: I realized my mess and made changes as documentation last night itself (should have update here as well )... but I still could not update the existing entity. Can you advise on mistake I am making ?